# `render': undefined method `access' when using jekyll multiple languages plugin

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm trying to setup [jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin](https://github.com/kurtsson/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin) for the first time.

The [example website](https://github.com/kurtsson/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin#7-example-website) works, indeed. Although, my own website does not.

This is the output, whenever I run `bundle exec jekyll serve --verbose`:

> /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin-1.7.0/lib/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin.rb:360:in `render': undefined method `access' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)

liquid:
`<div class="intro-lead-in">{% t page.header.text %}</div>`

pt.yml:

```
---
header:
  overlay: "no"
  text: It's Nice To Meet You
  button: Tell Me More
  buttonlink: "#services"
---
```

gemspec:

```
spec.required_ruby_version = '>= 2.5.0'
spec.add_runtime_dependency "jekyll", ">= 4.0", "< 4.3"
spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 2.0"
spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 13.0"
```

_config.yml

```
plugins:
  - jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin

languages: ["en", "pt"]

exclude_from_localizations: ["assets", "favicon.ico"]
```

Comment: You define two languages "en" and "pt", do you have both the `pt.yml` and `en.yml` file present? If so, do both files contain the same keys?

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes, for both questions. The problem only stops after removing `{% t page.header.text %}`, which is not helpful since I need to use it in order to translate the page.

Comment: That's strange, because that can only happen if [`site.parsed_translations[lang]`](https://github.com/kurtsson/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin/blob/v1.7.0/lib/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin.rb#L360) returns `false`. The value is to the result of a [`YAML.load_file`](https://github.com/kurtsson/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin/blob/v1.7.0/lib/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin.rb#L25) call. So either you have an empty file, or maybe the file is not located in the right directory.

Comment: @3limin4t0r worry not. I didn't understand you, at first. Indeed, that was problem. Feel free to create an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the exception is raised in the "jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin" gem let's have a quick look at the [source](https://github.com/kurtsson/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin/blob/v1.7.0/lib/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin.rb).

```
# lib/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin.rb:360
translation = site.parsed_translations[lang].access(key) if key.is_a?(String)
```

In order to generate the message *"undefined method `access' for false:FalseClass"* it means that `.access` is called upon `false`. Because the above only has one `access` call it means that `site.parsed_translations[lang]` must evaluate to `false`.

So how do you as library user influence this value? We'll first have to look at how this value came to be.

```
# lib/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin.rb:25
site.parsed_translations[lang] = YAML.load_file("#{site.source}/_i18n/#{lang}.yml")
```

This means that the `false` value is the return value of parsing one of your `.yml` files. The `YAML.load_file` documentation says the following about this return value:

> #### [load_file(filename, fallback: false)](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Psych.html#method-c-load_file)
>
> Load the document contained in `filename`. Returns the yaml contained in
> `filename` as a Ruby object, or if the file is empty, it returns the
> specified `fallback` return value, which defaults to `false`.

Here we can see that an empty file results in a `false` return value. So either your `_i18n/pt.yml` or `_i18n/en.yml` file is empty or the content within evaluates to `false`. Examples are `YAML.load('false') #=> false` and `YAML.load('no') #=> false`